# GKE how to have ingress modify existing load balancer

Tags: load-balancing, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

Is it possible to get GKE to augment the rules for an existing load balancer instead of creating a new one for each ingress object created?

We have multiple ingress objects created from multiple helm charts/releases, but there is no need for us to have multiple load balancers created for it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is use [nginx-ingress](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/#gce-gke) instead of GKE ingress.

When installed, a load balancer will be created for nginx-ingress service, and all your ingress will point to it.

Note, GKE Ingress uses Layer 7 LoadBalancer, and NGINX Ingress uses Layer 4, depending of how you are using the ingress, some adjustments in configuration would be needed.

Answer (score -2):

You can request a quota increase from the Google Cloud Console. The page [Load balancing resource quotas and limits](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/quotas) provides all the information that you need. If you click on the “Quota” link next to the rules you want to increase you will be redirected to the corresponding section in your GCP console. Make sure you check the box next to the quota, click on “EDIT QUOTAS” and on the right side of the screen you will see the form to send your request.

Comment: Sorry to vote down, but this doesn't answer the question asked here.  It's not about quotas, it's about how to configure multiple Ingresses to share a single External LB.